# Multiple volume collection with poemscol: Volume titles on verso pages

Tags: poetry

I'm making a collection on multiple volumes of poetry with poemscol. 
In `page 13` of poemscol manual says:

> Be sure to reset the style of page numbering (from \pagenumbering{roman} to \pagenumbering{arabic}) after issuing \putpoemcontents.

But if I put this command, the numbering goes to arabic as intended but also all the contents that should appear on recto pages start to appear on verso pages. Also `\leftheader` appears on right, and `\rightheader` on left.

Example code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt, twosided]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,geometry,makeidx, ifthen, keyval, multicol}
\usepackage{poemscol}
\begin{document}
\leftheader{Author -- in the leftheader}
\wholebooktitle{Poems collection book title}
\putpoemcontents
\makepoemcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{volumetitlepage}
\volumetitle{First volume title}
\volumeattribution{First volume attribution}
\end{volumetitlepage}

\poemtitle{First Poem}
\begin{poem}
    \begin{stanza}
        Now on you is the hungry equinox,\verseline
        \index{Now on you is the hungry equinox}
        O little stubborn people of the hill,\verseline
        \accidental{hill,] \sameword--- {\em Nation,\/} {\em Literary Digest\/}
            \sameword, {\em Vanderbilt\/} (I include the reading
            from {\em Vanderbilt\/}
            even though it is the same as in TSP, because
            {\em Vanderbilt\/} was published
            after the other magazine versions but before TSP.)}
        The season of the obscene moon whose pull\verseline
        Disturbs the sod, the rabbit, the lank fox,\verseline
        Moving the waters, the boar’s dull blood,\verseline
        And the acrid sap of the ironwood.\end{stanza}
    \begin{stanza}
        But breed no tender thing among the rocks.\verseline
        Rocks are too old under the mad moon,\verseline
        \accidental{old\missingpunct] \sameword, {\em Vanderbilt\/}}
        Renouncing passion by the strength that locks\verseline
        The eternal agony of fire in stone.\end{stanza}
\end{poem}
\clearpage
\poemtitle{Second Poem}
\begin{poem}
    \begin{stanza}
        Now on you is the hungry equinox,\verseline
        \index{Now on you is the hungry equinox}
        O little stubborn people of the hill,\verseline
        \accidental{hill,] \sameword--- {\em Nation,\/} {\em Literary Digest\/}
            \sameword, {\em Vanderbilt\/} (I include the reading
            from {\em Vanderbilt\/}
            even though it is the same as in TSP, because
            {\em Vanderbilt\/} was published
            after the other magazine versions but before TSP.)}
        The season of the obscene moon whose pull\verseline
        Disturbs the sod, the rabbit, the lank fox,\verseline
        Moving the waters, the boar’s dull blood,\verseline
        And the acrid sap of the ironwood.\end{stanza}
    \begin{stanza}
        But breed no tender thing among the rocks.\verseline
        Rocks are too old under the mad moon,\verseline
        \accidental{old\missingpunct] \sameword, {\em Vanderbilt\/}}
        Renouncing passion by the strength that locks\verseline
        The eternal agony of fire in stone.\end{stanza}
\end{poem}
\end{document}
```

And the result:
On page 1 you see the whole book title. And then the contents table, correctly on a recto page. But then the first volume title (just after using `\pagenumbering{arabic}`) is on a verso page. In the second poem you can see the numbering in arabic, and also the `\leftheader` on the right.

If I take out `\pagenumbering{arabic}` the titles appears on recto page, but the numbering continues in roman.

[image: first 3 pages]
[image: next 4 pages]

Comment: Many thanks for your example of `poemscol` usage - there are very few of that. I've no idea why, but LaTeX output is very sparse (pages of empty lines), and there is some error (have to type `s` to continue). Also the first line should contain `twoside` (not `twosided`) - at least for `pdflatex`. All other works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried issuing `\clearemptydoublepage` just after `\makepoemcontents`? That will ensure that the following content appears on a recto page.

I would put my main title page in a `maintitlepage` environment too (but that doesn't seem to be the origin of your problem).

Comment: In fact, putting \clearemptydoublepage after \makepoemcontents solve the issue.

Comment: Also John Burt is the creator of poemscol package. Thank you John!!